# How would you know if this is an ordinal index or not?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have seen this piece of code in an example via online using C#

> DataTable dt = ds.Tables["employees"];
>
> dt.Rows[0]["city"] = "Wilmington";

My question is what is the zero stands for? is it an ordinal index or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

0 references to the first row of the datatable. (zero-based counting)

Answer (score 2):

Look up [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) on MSDN and check out the property [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx). It returns an instance of [DataRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx).

It's not clear by the documentation, but non-array types can also implement the [] indexer. The DataRowCollection implements [int index] where index is the row to return. The collection can thus be accessed in the same manner as with an array, with the exception that this is a method call. It's for example not possible to pass return values from indexing methods as reference parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered by looking at the language you're using. C#'s standard is to use ordinal (0-based) indexes. X++, for example is 1-based. In general, you should look for other example code using indexes and see what those are using. The standard of 1-based or 0-based indexes should be used consistently throughout the language for both framework and user written.